# $wpdb select prepare statement

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am stuck on fixing  a serious issue that took too much time than it should. I know it might be a small thing, but i spent too much time only to create a simple select query. Here is the code i am using to look at and tell me what is going wrong.

```
global $wpdb;
    $querystr = "
    SELECT $wpdb->posts.ID 
    FROM $wpdb->posts
    WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'product'
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_title = $tour_name
";

$productids = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);

foreach ($productids as $productid) {
echo $productid;
}
```

Comment: Your question is missing any proper description of what “going wrong” means ... so I can only guess that it is probably the missing quotes around the tour name. (And depending on where that value comes from, it is likely missing any protection against SQL injection as well.)

Comment: You tell us "what is going wrong" and we will try to tell you how to fix it. ;-)

Comment: You really need to explain what you are trying to do, what is happening and what you want to happen. Otherwise, you have no chance of anyone here being able to help you resolve your issue.

Comment: @CBroe thanks for your response. This piece of code is being used along with other PHP code in my custom function file in a wordpress theme. But It comes out with no results. When i serached online for the most secured SQL statements, i found out that prepare statement are the one. Would you suggest a better solution for this.

Comment: Well it most likely doesn’t give results, because the query is faulty. // How to use prepared statements, can be found in the example in the documentation: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Comment: Are you sure it's not **`->post`**? `$wpdb->posts.`

Answer (score 0):

Use [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Methods_and_Properties) class to retrieve data from the database, most of the time it is more convenient than writing full queries manually, not to mention that it uses prepared statements and escapes data properly.

```
$query = new WP_Query([ 
  'post_type' => 'product',
  'title' => $tour_name
]);
```

To fetch only id-s use [wp_list_pluck](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pluck):

```
$post_ids = wp_list_pluck( $query->posts, 'ID' );
```